# R error (fisher test): all entries of x must be nonnegative and finite

Tags: r

Here is my code below:

```
 d2 <- data.frame(cbind(1:10, sapply(1:4, function(x) { sample(1:25, size = 10, replace = TRUE) })))

 pvals <- rep(0, nrow(d2))

 for (n in 1:nrow(d2)) 
  {
  pvals[n] <- fisher.test(
    matrix(d2[n, 2:5], nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  )$p.value
  }
```

Where is my error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the OP's code, we need `unlist` to unlist `data.frame` structure into a `vector` before creating the `matrix` as each row extraction is a `data.frame`

```
str(d2[1, 2:5])
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ X2: int 22
# $ X3: int 12
# $ X4: int 19
# $ X5: int 12
```

and this creates a `list` when we call `matrix`

```
str(matrix(d2[1, 2:5], 2, 2))
#List of 4
# $ : int 22
# $ : int 12
# $ : int 19
# $ : int 12
# - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 2 2
```

If we `unlist`, the structure becomes

```
str(matrix(unlist(d2[1, 2:5]), 2, 2))
#int [1:2, 1:2] 22 12 19 12
```

Making the changes in the OP's code

```
pvals <- rep(0, nrow(d2))
for (n in 1:nrow(d2)) {
   pvals[n] <- fisher.test(
      matrix(unlist(d2[n, 2:5]), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
     )$p.value
  }

pvals
#[1] 0.80226381499 0.09361771430 0.23302332741 0.00001155306 0.76106849673 0.81049227216 0.14211831663 0.28974696874 0.00140855512
#[10] 0.04810238920
```

---

Another option is `apply`, where we specify the `MARGIN = 1` for rowwise looping

```
apply(d2[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) fisher.test(matrix(x, 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))$p.value)
#[1] 0.80226381499 0.09361771430 0.23302332741 0.00001155306 0.76106849673 0.81049227216 0.14211831663 0.28974696874 0.00140855512
#[10] 0.04810238920
```